# duplicates list edited from ... to

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, дубликаты

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/709649/revisions

[image: скриншот]

> duplicates list edited from [Потеря контекста вызова](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/535030/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0) to [Потеря контекста вызова](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/535030/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0), [Почему this в onclick необязателен?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/624717/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-this-%d0%b2-onclick-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8f%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd)

Надо бы перевести.

Comment: Кстати, если нажать [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/709649/3), там вообще номера вместо названий.

Comment: Завёл смежный [баг на MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300141/339911).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавил переводы:

- > duplicates list edited
  >   список дубликатов изменён
- > duplicates list edited from $initialLinks$ to $newLinks$`
  >   список дубликатов изменён с $initialLinks$ на $newLinks$.

Появится на сайте после обновления transifex и пересборки.